# Como faço para pegar valores atualizados de uma pagina com puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, atualização, puppeteer

Minha duvida e a seguinte, estou criando um codigo onde ele vai entrar no site da *[blaze](https://blaze.com/pt/games/double)* e vai pegar os 3 ultimos digitos sorteados no site e imprimir no console. O meu codigo atual , ele esta pegando os 3 ultimos digitos da primeira execuçao do codigo, sendo que a cada 15 senhundos eu quero que ele pegue os novos numeros gerados no site.

**Meu codigo atual esta assim:**

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://blaze.com/pt/games/double');
  
  const dados = await page.evaluate(() => {

    return {
        numero1: document.querySelector("#roulette-recent > div > div.entries.main > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div").innerText,
        numero2: document.querySelector("#roulette-recent > div > div.entries.main > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div").innerText,
        numero3: document.querySelector("#roulette-recent > div > div.entries.main > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div").innerText
    }
    
})

function pegar() {
    
    console.log(dados)
    

}

setInterval(pegar, 5000)

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

Não sei se é a melhor opção mas a estratégia abaixo funciona conforme você precisa. Você pode usar como base e ir aprimorando.

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    async function scrapping() {

   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.goto('https://blaze.com/pt/games/double');

   const dados = await page.evaluate(() => {

    return {
        numero1: document.querySelector("#roulette-recent > div > div.entries.main > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div").innerText,
        numero2: document.querySelector("#roulette-recent > div > div.entries.main > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div").innerText,
        numero3: document.querySelector("#roulette-recent > div > div.entries.main > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div").innerText
    }

})
await browser.close()
console.log(dados)
    }

    const delayPage = (milliseconds) => {

   return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
    }, milliseconds);
});
    }
    
    async function execute() {
    const loop = 1
    while (loop < 10000) {
    await scrapping()
    await delayPage(15000)
}
}
 execute()
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Essa sugestão é como eu faria, você pode utilizar bibliotecas de cron. Elas executam atividades em um tempo determinado por você, por exemplo você pode botar para ele verificar sempre de 15 em 15 segundos, ou todo dia as 9 da manhã e assim vai, sua criatividade é o limite. Pode usar como base esse site onde ele faz uma api de lembrete, ele utiliza cron: https://www.twilio.com/blog/envie-lembretes-diarios-via-sms-usando-as-plataformas-firebase-node-js-e-twilio